# Filtering trash from a JSON file before reading it into PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following file, which was supposed to be a JSON file, but it has a string slapped right before the actual JSON content (they are separated by a tab!):

```
string_smth\t{id:"str", num:0}
string_smth1\t{id:"str2", num:1}
string_smth2\t{id:"str3", num:2}
string_smth3\t{id:"str4", num:3}
```

Doing the following returns null for all columns:

```
import pyspark.sql
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
schema = StructType([
       StructField("id", StringType()),
       StructField("num", IntegerType())
])

df = spark.read.json("hdfs:///path/files.json/*", schema=schema)

df.show()

+--+---+
|id|num|
+--+---+
|null|null|
|null|null|
|null|null|
|null|null|
```

Any way of fixing that during the `spark.read.json` call? If not, what are my options?

Comment: A quick (but dirty way) to resolve this would be to split every line on '{' and then drop the first part.

Comment: @ChukUltima, I would call it tricky way not dirty way. please post answer to help the OP

Comment: @ChukUltima They are separated by a tab, btw.

Comment: Read it as a tab-delimited file using spark-csv and then use `from_json` on the second column to get a `struct(id, num)`

Comment: @philantrovert can't find an example on how to read a tsv. Can you post one?

Comment: `spark.read.csv("file" , sep='\t')` doesn't work?

Comment: @philantrovert it did, now I am struggling with the second part

Comment: @philantrovert how do I select the second column if it is not named?

Comment: It should have `_c1` as the default name. if not, use `df.printSchema` to see.

Comment: @philantrovert I used `df.schema.names` and found the `_c1`, now I am using this: `new_df = functions.from_json(df.select('_c1'), schema=schema)` but I am getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`

Comment: @philantrovert any tips? maybe I am calling from_json incorrectly?

Comment: It should be `from_json(col('_c1') , schema=schema)` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several issues in your file, but maybe it is just a problem related to your example.

I created a rdd :

```
a = sc.parallelize(['string_smth\t{"id":"str","num":0}',
'string_smth1\t{"id":"str2","num":1}',
'string_smth2\t{"id":"str3","num":2}',
'string_smth3\t{"id":"str4","num":3}'])
```

In your case, replace this `sc.parallelize` with `sc.textFile(path_to_file)` to acquire the file you need. 
As you can see, the `id` is enclosed with double quotes. That is how a json is supposed to be in a string format. And also, technically, you do not have space after the comma. How is your original file exactly ?

Then, just do this :

```
import json
schema = StructType([
       StructField("id", StringType()),
       StructField("num", IntegerType())
])
a.map(lambda x : json.loads(x.split('\t')[1])).toDF(schema).show()

+----+---+
|  id|num|
+----+---+
| str|  0|
|str2|  1|
|str3|  2|
|str4|  3|
+----+---+
```

Comment: It is tab separated `string tab json_dict`.

Comment: I changed the split with `\t`. It is even better ;)

Comment: @ivan_bilan I forgot the `json.loads` function. Just added it

Comment: I guess I am doing smth wrong. When I use sc.textFile I get: `'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'textFile'`.

Comment: @ivan_bilan you should get sparkContext from SparkSession object

Comment: @ivan_bilan if not you will have to create sparkContext object and not sparkSession object

Answer (score 1):

**json, struct and case class don't need schema to be created.**

**You can use `sparkContext`'s `textFile` api to read the text file and parse the lines to get the *valid json strings***

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path to the csv file")\
    .map(lambda line: line.split("\t", 1)[1].replace("id:", "\"id\":").replace("num:", "\"num\":"))
```

Then finally convert the *valid json rdds* to `dataframe`

```
df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
```

which should give you

```
+----+---+
|id  |num|
+----+---+
|str |0  |
|str2|1  |
|str3|2  |
|str4|3  |
+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution would be to split on the '{' character for each line :

```
json_lin = '{' + 'string_smth {id:"str", num:0}'.split('{')[-1]
```

Comment: I need this in PySpark.